# Dependency Injection: Injecting configuration in .Net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, configuration, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm migrating some old software to .Net core 2.0 ...

I'd like to inject a connection string in my class DBActivityRepository from a base class...

Should I just pass the configuration in the creation of the base class

```
this._DBHandler = new DBHandler(configuration);
```

or is it better to do it this way:

```
private DBHandler _DBHandler;
private string connectionString;
public DBActivityRepository(IConfiguration configuration) : base(configuration)
{
    // **Do I need this?**
    this._DBHandler = new DBHandler(configuration);
    connectionString = this._DBHandler.GetConnectionString();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1204089/ASP-NET-Core-Dependency-Injection

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If DBHandler is your base class and DbActivityRepository is a subclass of DBHandler, is not necessary to create an instance of DBHandler into the DBActivityRepository, you can use their public and protected methods/properties directly (inheritance), something like this:

```
public interface IConfiguration
{
    string GetConnectionString();
}

public abstract class DbHandler
{
    protected DbHandler(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        ConnectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString();
    }

    protected string ConnectionString { get; }
}

public class DbActivityRepository : DbHandler
{
    public DbActivityRepository(IConfiguration configuration) 
        : base(configuration)
    {
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        // use your connStr
        Console.Write(ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For dependency injection in asp.net core you need to use built-in DI engine. 
At first, you need create appsetting.json.

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "NameOfContext":"server=localhost;userid=root;password=password;"
}
```

Second, create options type for connection strings and other properties what you need to read from appsettings.json.

For IServiceCollection services read properties from appsettings.json:

```
services.Configure<YourServiceOptions>(_config["ConnectionStrings:NameOfContext"])
```

And, the last step is init your db connection:

```
services.AddDbContext<NameOfContext>(builder => builder.UseMySql(options.ConnectionString));
```

This only works with MySql.

Comment: @Florian Koch...  But in my case the DI is in Class library (DAL) , that Class is shared in a MVC project. I need to Inject the connection string in DAL for centralize in all the implementations.

Comment: @Cicciux sorry but this isn't my answer, I just improved the formatting